# What exactly is slam death metal?

Tags: genre, metal, style

What exactly is it, what is the differences between say deathcore and slam death, what are the main differences, does it have more than one sound? All the slam i have heard sounds like devourment.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Mezmerizer/Slam_Death_Metal might help  you.

Comment: Deathcore is basically going to be like slam death except a little more poppy.

Comment: Lolno, brutal deathcore is a more rhythmically focused version of brutal death metal, with a heavy core metal/rock influence.

Comment: I was hoping the answer was going to be that people put on a beret (black naturally) and went to coffee shops for improvised recitals of death metal by other attendees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically a slower "brutal death metal" with emphasis on slamdowns and breakdowns. That's probably all it really is, so you can do a lot with it and it can still be called "slam death" if you just follow the basics, combine it, or whatever.

Comment: Actually, devourment copied suffocation, a lot of brutal/slam death bands probably do, but i don't know many. :P

Comment: Yes, basically, "slam death metal" = "slower brutal death metal". Nowadays almost every brutal death metal band uses some breakdowns in their music.

Answer (score 1):

Most brutal genre of metal to ever exist besides grindcore/goregrind.
And yes, with slams and breakdowns. Think an improved version of deathcore and 1000 times more brutal.

Bands like Guttural Slug, Visceral Disgorge, Abominable Putridity, Vulvodynia, Kraanium, Cerebral Bore, Cerebral Incubation, and Short Bus Pileup.

Comment: Is this your definition? Do you have any sources you could reference to back this up?